# Can't capture video from dshow device. FFmpeg finish immediately resulting empty file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, recording, vhs, digitisation

I'm digitizing my old tape recordings from usb dongle. Everything been ok, I digitized several tapes, but I'm abandoned this project for a while and reinstalled windows. Keeping on secondary drive the same ffmpeg binaries and noted .txt file with recording options.

Now I tried to return to work, but in attempts to start recording ffmpeg just finishing immediately:

```
D:\video>ffmpeg -f dshow -crossbar_video_input_pin_number 2 -video_size 720x576
-rtbufsize 2G -framerate 25 -pixel_format yuyv422 -i video="AVerMedia USB Polari
s Analog Capture":audio="Analog Audio In (AVerMedia C039" -copyts -c:v rawvideo
-c:a pcm_s16le -t 06:00 019.avi
ffmpeg version N-91930-g0caa33c60b Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lib
freetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amr
wb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --
enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-l
ibwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --
enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --en
able-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --en
able-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --e
nable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enab
le-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavformat    58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.103 / 58.  4.103
  libavfilter     7. 29.100 /  7. 29.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=AVerMedia USB Polaris Analog Capture:audio=Analog A
udio In (AVerMedia C039':
  Duration: N/A, start: 27907.394000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, 25 fps,
25 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to '019.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.18.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, q=2-31,
165888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.30.100 rawvideo
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1411 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.30.100 pcm_s16le
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=07:45:07.80 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=      96kB time=07:45:07.80 bitrate=   0.0kbits/
s speed=4.09e+04x
video:0kB audio:86kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 11.267573%

D:\video>
```

But ffplay playing stream properly and I can watch it

```
D:\video>ffplay -hide_banner -f dshow -crossbar_video_input_pin_number 2 -video_
size 720x576 -rtbufsize 2G -framerate 25 -pixel_format yuyv422 -i video="AVerMed
ia USB Polaris Analog Capture":audio="Analog Audio In (AVerMedia C039"
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=AVerMedia USB Polaris Analog Capture:audio=Analog A
udio In (AVerMedia C039':
  Duration: N/A, start: 27057.813000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, 25 fps,
25 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
27060.50 A-V:  0.010 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=12961KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

I'm stuck and have no idea what can it be. Please help.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the -copyts or switch `-t 06:00` to `-vframes 9000`

Comment: Thank you, removing `-copyts` parameter worked for me!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This command line work for me:

```
ffplay -f dshow -video_size 720x480 -framerate 29.97 -i video="Conexant Polaris Video Capture":audio="Conexant Polaris Video Capture"
```

before testing any command line, identify the name of your capture card in the operating system with the line below:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

after that, see what resolutions are supported and the frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Conexant Polaris Video Capture"
```

When listing the capture options for my card, I realized that when it uses 29.97 frame rate it doesn't support 720x576 resolution, but 720x480.